# How to select unique value of element with same id using jQuery

Tags: jsp, jquery

```
<c:forEach var="projects" items="${projectList}">
    <tr>
        <td class="font ">
            <a href="#" id="projectname" name="projectname" class="testone" >${projects.name}</a>
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" id="hello" value="${projects.projid}"/>
    </tr>                     
</c:forEach>
```

Basically, my code iterates one value from the database to the next. Specific to mention, the INPUT in `<input type="hidden" id="hello" value="${projects.projid}"/>` changes its value each iteration. However, when i select it through jQuery, i cannot get the 2nd value of PROJID from the database.

Here's my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#projectname').click(function(){
        $(this).each(function(i){
            var choice = $('#hello').val()  
            $('#right').load('show_project_details',{projectid:choice});
        });
    });
});
```

I know that selecting with an ID is restrained to the first element but doesnt my code have a work around? I'm really trying to avoid radio buttons.

If you have the time please do reply. Thank you very much!

Comment: HTML doesn't allow multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes instead.

Comment: I m surprised how you made it to have same ID to more than one element in HTML.

Comment: As i mentioned in the post, im aware that same ID elements does not work and i am looking for alternatives, if there is such and @sp00m posted the answer below. Thanks Christian and Murtaza!

Using classes does not solve my problem. It collates all the values i am getting. Christian Varga . My post is a different case from previous ones.

Comment: hey guys ( @christian varga ) if you guys are wondering a workaround to how to select values with same ids check out sp00m's post below and vote if you can! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML id attribute should have a unique value within your whole HTML document.

So, change your JSP like this:

```
<c:forEach var="projects" items="${projectList}">
    <tr>
        <td class="font">
            <a href="#" class="projectname">${projects.name}</a>
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="projectid${projects.projid}" value="${projects.projid}" />
    </tr>                     
</c:forEach>
```

And then, use this JavaScript instead of yours:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.projectname").click(function() {
        var choice = $(this).parent().next().val();
        $('#right').load('show_project_details', {projectid: choice});
    });
});
```

Comment: WOW! Worked like magic! Thank you very much for this @sp00m !